# Unable to round the image corners second time

Tags: android

I am trying to add rounded corners to images in my android app. The code which I am using for adding rounded corners is:

```
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final SeekBar cornerRadius = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    final TextView tip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tip);

    bm = getRoundedCornerBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath),
            cornerRadius.getProgress());
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

The above corner radius is got from the value of seekbar.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

The code for saving the pic to sd card which I am invoking on click of save button is:

```
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(picturePath);
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri
                .parse("file://"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Pic save successfuly. Path : " + picturePath,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The problem I face is that once an image has been edited to have rounded corners. The next time, I open the same image and try saving with different corner radius value doesn't save the image. I do get the above Toast message second time though but the image remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. The Read and write permissions were messed up.